# Validating that each project imports our Common.Targets

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I run a fairly-large team (5 solutions, ~150 projects), using TFS2010 and gated check-ins. In our team, we mandate that each project import a file of our own called Common.Targets, which does a bunch of build-time stuff. I've instructed everyone on the team to do that, and wrote a wiki entry on it too.

However, people still forget to import common.Targets when adding a new project, causing all sorts of trouble after check-in.

Is there a way - an msbuild commandline, something I can put in my .sln's, etc. - that such a project would fail to compile, and therefore would not pass the gated check-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

1. As suggested by KMoraz, author a custom check-in policy [(How To)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb668980.aspx) which parses changed/added .csproj as XML and validates that they import Common.Targets.

   Con: Need to distribute this manually to all developers in the team, and manage updates if there are any.
2. Author a custom CodeActivity [(How To)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2009/06/01/writing-custom-activities-for-tfs-build-2010-beta-1.aspx). It runs msbuild MSBuildEmitSolution=1, parses the resulting .sln.metaproj as XML to get the list of csproj files, and then validates them as above.

   Con: Developer only sees the error when his gated check-in fails.

I decided to go with 2.

Comment: There's a way to [distribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2011/03/27/distributing-custom-check-in-policies-amp-wit-controls-using-team-members.aspx) policies using the TFS Power Tools. Haven't tried that myself.

Answer (score 3):

A classic approach would be a check-in policy. Since there's no pre-defined policy for your requirement, you can fairly easily write your own custom policy - see [How To: Create Custom Check-in Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb668980.aspx).

Comment: Yes, this Checkin policy could look into the pending changes for .csproj files (or other type of project you care about) and make a XML query to check there's the right target import.

Comment: Thanks. This means that I'll have to deploy my check-in policy DLL to everyone on the team. Not fun, but I guess I'll have to.